# "turn + -ing" vs turn + infinitive"

Tags: gerunds, infinitives

When using the noun *turn*, should I use the `+ing` form or the infinitive?

- Whose turn is it **to do** the washing up?
- Whose turn is it **doing** the washing up?

Comment: I don't know the exact rules, but the second example is definitely  wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Turn* is a little tricky.

Both *turn to do X* and *turn doing X* are found, but under different circumstances.

You use the infinitive when you are referring to the point in time at which the action starts, when the  action lies in the  future::

> It's Jack's turn to drive now.
>   When it was Betty's turn to speak we all left to get coffee.
>   Next week is Fred's turn to host the party.

But when you're referring to the action as an entirety, with duration, you use the gerund:

> Sarah took my turn chairing the committee, because I was called out of town.
>   During Mike's turn watching the dials Anne keyed in the data they'd accumulated.

Answer (score 0):

arah took my turn chairing the committee, because I was called out of town.
During Mike's turn watching the dials Anne keyed in the data they'd a

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/138065)